# Get complete data of a transaction in Stripe

Tags: symfony, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

How can I get the complete information of transaction in Stripe?

For the fields which I filled at the `Charge::create()`, I want to get all the details: number,cvc,exp_month,exp_year  ect.

I can get amount and id by using this server call

`BalanceTransaction::retrieve($data['transactionID']);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
charge:retrive("ch_%yourid");
```

you give you complete charge data , but give you last 4 digits of card number only.